# With Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10, why do I have to run commands to enable two finger scrolling?

Tags: drivers, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics, input

When I run the following commands in the terminal the radio button in the mouse options will enable two finger scrolling.  If I do not run these commands first, then scrolling radio button no longer does anything and I lose scrolling completely if I tick the radio button.  What would be the best solution?

```
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1 1
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 32 10
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 32 8
```

Answer (score 1):

just search mouse in unity select and open Mouse and Touchpad.
go to touch pad tab
and enable two finger scrolling

Comment: It's not completely clear, but he's tried that and it doesn't work.  When you tick the "two finger" option, you lose all scrolling.  Only the `xinput` commands above will activate it.  I have the same problem on my Toshiba Sattelite Pro U400 and I've given up trying to get it to work reliably, even though the `xinput` commands will work for me too.  The problem is that they often disappear when you suspend/resume.  Too much hassle for such a small feature.  I just use side-scrolling on that laptop now.